# how to configure server odbc for postgresql windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

i want to put in the server machine the database postgresql
and i have also to define the client 
can you tell me how i'm going to configure odbc data source to connect
os:windows
thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and Install the Postgres ODBC driver (http://psqlodbc.projects.postgresql.org/)
2. Configure it as you would any other ODBC data source. [Additional info here](http://psqlodbc.projects.postgresql.org/).
3. In the future, **Google**. These were literally the first and third results I got for `postgres odbc driver`.